# LDA same as QDA classifier when include all quadratic terms

Tags: machine-learning, classification, discriminant-analysis

On pg. 159 of "An Introduction to Statistical Learning
with Applications in R" by Hastie et al. [http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf] they are talking about LDA vs. QDA classifiers and say:

"If we added all possible quadratic terms and
cross-products to LDA, the form of the model would be the same as the
QDA model, although the parameter estimates would be different. This
device allows us to move somewhere between an LDA and a QDA model."

I understand the basics of these 2 methods but can you please show me mathematically:

1. how the form of the LDA model becomes the same as QDA
2. how/why the "parameter estimates would be different"